# URL Matrix Parameter vs Path Parameter

Tags: rest

I have a REST API that is to be used to query multidimensional data, the dimensions can vary depending on the data being queried, but for the sake of this example lets say there is COUNTRY, INDICATOR and SEX.  The user can query on any (or none) of the dimensions, and for each dimension they can provide one or more values:

I need to design an API that can take key value(s) pairs, my original design was this:

http://myapi/data/providerA?COUNTRY=UK;FR;DE&SEX=M

But then the best practise tells me that the resource should be path parameters, so something like this:

http://myapi/data/COUNTRY=UK+FR+DE,SEX=M/providerA

Then I have found matrix parameters, so perhaps this:

http://myapi/data;COUNTRY=UK+FR+DE;SEX=M/providerA

The question in my mind is, **what is better for this use case PATH parameters, or Matrix Parameters?**

Matrix parameters are not an official part of the w3 standard, but does it offer advantages over using Path.  I can think of perhaps HTTP 304 (as the order of matrix parameters should be irrelevant), and I have not really seen path parameters used as a way to provide one or more filters in a path segment (i.e everything between two /).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first question you should ask is what **resource** are you modelling? This is not immediately clear to me by looking at your example...

It would appear that you have data of the type `data` and that an identifier for that data is `providerA`. If this is a meaningful resource to the users of your API we are fine, but perhaps be a bit more descriptive?

---

I know there are some that advocate "path parameters" similar to your second example, but to me this syntax is really weird as there is no valid name for the path segment between `data` and `providerA`...

Path parameters use **placeholders** in an **URI template** such as `{name}` in:

```
/myapi/data/{name}
```

Now if this "data provider" resource represents content that can optionally be *filtered* by COUNTRY, INDICATOR and SEX I would use query parameters.

On the other hand if these parameters really represent different dimensions of the same resource I would model that as **matrix** parameters

```
/myapi/data;country=UK,FR,DE;sex=M;indicator=X/providerA
```

(Note that matrix parameters should probably be separated by comma and not space encoded space characters)

I think of matrix parameters defining a different **namespace** for the path segment to which they are attached.

---

Matrix parameters are attached to a path segment so the following example

```
/widget;brand=acme/12345/image;type=packshot
```

... should be read as "the image of type packshot for widget 12345 of brand acme". Regardless of REST dogma it is probably more readable and easily interpreted than a query string tagged on to the end:

```
/widget/12345/image?brand=acme&type=packshot
```